# How to remove empty select menu tag with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: drop-down-menu

I want to remove empty select menu tags from my html page.

```
<select name="test"></select>  --- remove

<select name="test"> <option value="test">test</option> </select>  --- do not remove
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Preferably suppress the empty SELECT in server-side code. But if you insist on using client-side techniques:

```
$('select:empty').remove();
```